# How to tell make to never re-make prerequsities?

Tags: makefile

I have a Makefile where `a: b` and  `b: c`. When I run `make a` while `b` exists, I expect Make to leave `b` alone even if `c` does not exist. But it seems like GNU Make goes all the way up the tree, and remakes everything down from the most upstream parent that has an issue.

There is a flag `--always-make` that cause Make to always remake all prerequisites, even if not needed. Unfortunately, there does not appear to be a `--never-make` flag that never remakes any prerequisites, even if needed. Is there a general way I can get this behavior?

Some possible solutions that don't seem suitable:

- `touch`ing every file one by one is tedious, and in the case of missing files, results in empty "fake" files which I find far too hacky
- Commenting out the prereq as in `a: #b` breaks Make variables like `touch $<`.
- Commenting out the rule for `b:` works, but often there are quite a few b scattered throughout the file, so this is a lot of commenting and also tedious

Comment: No, there is no make option that you can use for that. You will have to modify your Makefile, even if it is tedious, or `touch --date=very-long-time-ago c`  for all `c` prerequisites.

Answer (score 0):

If you're sure that doesn't need recreate `c` maybe:

```
a:  b
    echo a

b:  c
    echo b

c:
    [ -e b ] || ( generate c... )
```

In target `c` we check existence of `b` (`[ -e b]`) and if yes we do nothing (else `generate c...`).

The `c` target is run when `c` doesn't exist but if `b` too doesn't generate `c` (I think it takes many time in your case).